# Уникальные значения столбца df которые не входят в другой столбец

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Есть 2 датафрейма:

```
data2 = {'CustomerID': ['c27boh'],
         'unique_codes': ['cjncee']}
data1 = {'CustomerID': ['c27boh'],
         'unique_codes': ['cjncee, cktvug']}
```

Нужно по каждому CustomerID сравнить значения в unique_codes  и заполнить в новом столбце датафрейма data1 только те уникальные значения из unique_codes, которых нет в data2.

data1:

| CustomerID | unique_codes |
| --- | --- |
| c27boh | cjncee |

data2:

| CustomerID | unique_codes |
| --- | --- |
| c27boh | cjncee, cktvug |

Ожидаемый результат:
data1

| CustomerID | unique_codes | new_unique_codes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| c27boh | cjncee, cktvug | cktvug |

Comment: В каком новом столбце? Приведите и то, что должно на выходе получиться. Ну и напишите, в чём у вас собственно проблема, что вы уже пробовали сами сделать.

Comment: У вас пример не соответствует коду в начале вопроса. Перепутаны местами `data1` и `data2`, разберитесь что из чего нужно вычитать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант решения с использованием `.merge()` с аргументом `indicator=True`, который показывает, из какого фрейма взяты данные при слиянии.

```
data2 = {'CustomerID': ['c27boh'],
         'unique_codes': ['cjncee']}
data1 = {'CustomerID': ['c27boh'],
         'unique_codes': ['cjncee, cktvug']}

df = (pd.DataFrame(data1).set_index('CustomerID').unique_codes.str.split('\s*,\s*').explode().to_frame()
      .merge(pd.DataFrame(data2).set_index('CustomerID'), on=['CustomerID', 'unique_codes'], how='outer', indicator=True))
df._merge = df.unique_codes.where(df._merge.eq('left_only'))
df = df.groupby('CustomerID').agg(lambda col: ', '.join(col.dropna())).rename(columns={'_merge': 'new_unique_codes'}).reset_index()
print(df)
```

```
  CustomerID    unique_codes new_unique_codes
0     c27boh  cjncee, cktvug           cktvug
```

Answer (score 0):

Что-то самому стало интересно. Ну, решение в общем-то "влоб", не уверен, что можно проще сделать:

```py
data1['new_unique_codes'] = data1.join(data2, rsuffix='_') \
    .apply(lambda x: ','.join(set(x['unique_codes'].split(',')) 
                            - set(x['unique_codes_'].split(','))), axis=1)
```

Просто вычитаем из одного множества другое. Ну, попутно нужно сначала разбить строки по запятой, а в конце что получилось наоборот склеить.